# Open Source Software for Community Credit Union

Tags: open-source, finance

I'm looking for a piece of open source software to help run a small community [credit union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_union) (400-1,000 members). It will be able to handle payments, banking and ledger systems.

It's a long shot, but if anyone has anything they could suggest it would be superb.

Comment: As a start you should probably support Software Freedom Conservancy's NPOAcct: https://sfconservancy.org/npoacct/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest two Open Source options:

- [GnuCash](https://www.gnucash.org/), a GUI application, and
- [ledger](https://www.ledger-cli.org/) a CLI application.

You can also have a look at the [Plain-Text Accounting](https://plaintextaccounting.org/) site, which lists many tools available in that ecosystem. There are also tools and libraries available to convert the data between the two options above (and others).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you try out [Mifos](https://mifos.org/). It is an open source Web-based system that can be self-hosted. You can download it on [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mifos/). You can also try out a demo [here](https://mifos.org/mifos-x/demo/). It will work on a Windows or Linux platform. Mifos has:

- Client Management e.g.details, identity mgt, documents, family members etc.
- Loans & Savings Portfolio Tracking: set up loans, savings, fixed deposits, etc. and track to client payments, etc.
- Accounting Support – chart of accounts, ledgers, balance sheet etc
- Reporting for Clients, Loans, Savings, Accounting, etc.

You can also search its forums on sourceforge and the main site, if you have any specific questions not addressed. I have installed and explored a local copy on a previous project.

It may have more than you need. But you can limit usage to what you require.